# How did I exceed the daily reputation limit?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

I didn't  even know there was a daily reputation limit until I earned this badge today, and I appear to have exceeded it already.  Curious.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess as per the duplicate target, its likely you got an accepted answer.